# Where can I find the connection url for my Google Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

To enhance my classes with DataNucleus I need to know my connection url for my Google Datastore. I searched most settings of the console but I can't seem to find it. Does anybody knows where I can find it?

I'm using this guide to set everything up: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jpa/guides/eclipse.html

Comment: It does not exist. Why do you need it? Did you check "Datanucleus" option in App Engine settings?

Comment: I suppose your on eclipse, Java SDK.why don't you just set  DataNucleus to auto enhance ?? At any point you need to enhance all classes, just close the project and reopen

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I don't see any option in App Engine settings called "Datanucleus". But since I'm new at using the App Engine I'm mayby overlooking it?

Comment: Datastore doesn't use a connection URL, it's just 'there' - available for all App Engine apps to use.

Comment: Ah oke, that explains some things :)

Comment: as an aside, that link says nothing about knowing any URL to *enhance* your classes. The URL is to create the schema in your datastore (whatever datastore that is), since the URL is to tell it where is the datastore. And DataNucleus 4.0 does not support GAE/Datastore; you need v3.0/3.1 for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Eclipse, open Project > Properties > Google > App Engine. Check "Use Datanucleus JDO/JPA to access the Datastore".

Note that in the left menu you can choose ORM and Validation options under App Engine.

Make sure that you included all the necessary jars:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview#Enhancing_Data_Classes

Comment: First I'll Install the Google plugin, and I'll try you solution! Thx in advance!